# How to create csrf token in html form in leaflet pop-up?

Tags: javascript, django, forms, csrf, leaflet

How do I create a csrf token in a leaflet pop-up, so that the user can post some text to a database by interacting with the form? I've added the `{% csrf_token %}` tag to a simple html form, which works fine, but it doesn't work when I put it in the content section of the pop-up, though the other html elements work fine.

```
map.on('click', function(e) {
 var popupContent = '<p>What would you like to post to this location? <form action="/post_temp/" method="post"> {% csrf_token %} <p> <input type="text" name="post"> </p> <input type="submit" value="Post"> </form>',  
 popup = new L.Popup();  
 popup.setLatLng(e.latlng);
 popup.setContent(popupContent);
 map.openPopup(popup);
```

});

Basically when I leave the token in, the Leaflet map doesn't load altogether, but if I leave it out, I get a CSRF token missing or incorrect error.

I'm a bit new to all this (javascript/leaflet/web dev/django) so I'm not sure where the problem is coming from or where I should start? I imagine I will have to poke around the leaflet.js code but I'm not confident I'll be able to make sense of it. Any advice where clearly to go or some code I could insert, or just why (in laymen terms) the code isn't working much appreciated!

Comment: I could well be wrong here as there's not really quite enough in the question to diagnose, but I suspect that your JavaScript file is not actually generated by the Django templating system, and hence the tag you've put in won't do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can send `csrfmiddlewaretoken` by youself

```
$.post("/view_func/", 
      {
        yourself_var:yourself_data,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken:getCookie('csrftoken'),//or use $.cookie
      }, 
      function(data) {
       //handler result
      }
    )

function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1)); 
                break;
            }    
        }    
    }    
    return cookieValue;
}
```

enjoy it

Answer (score 0):

For anybody's future reference, the reason the original poster's code failed is because in Django,

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

renders as single-quote html elements.  Because Django's template language renders before any of the JavaScript or html elements, the quotes will be messed up. If the original author converted all single quotes to double quotes, and the double quotes to single quotes, the code will work.

```
map.on('click', function(e) {
 var popupContent = "<p>What would you like to post to this location? <form action='/post_temp/' method='post'> {% csrf_token %} <p> <input type='text' name='post'> </p> <input type='submit' value='Post'> </form>",  
 popup = new L.Popup();  
 popup.setLatLng(e.latlng);
 popup.setContent(popupContent);
 map.openPopup(popup);
```

The above corrected code will work.